# What is adder in this code snippet? I can't find an answer

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I'm trying to figure out what is a const variable if we assign it to a `array.push` method

```
const numbers = [0,33,4,1]
const adder = numbers.push(2)
```

What does adder become here ?
If i write it in the console it gives me the length of the numbers array.
Is it bad practice to assign an array method to a variable ?

Comment: The `push()` method modifies the array, and returns the new size of the array. This allows you to combine `numbers.push(2); adder = numbers.length;`

Comment: You're not assigning an array method, but the value returned by a method. This is 100% normal

Comment: "The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does adder become here ?

It's assigned the return value of `push`. So look at [the documentation for `push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

So it is the length of the array.

---

> Is it bad practice to assign an array method to a variable ?

In *general* (there are exceptions) it isn't *useful* to assign an array method to a variable … but that isn't what this code is doing. The return value of a method is not the method itself.